# Ping to home computer results in 'Request Timed Out', although computer is connected & online

Tags: http, dns, ip, ping, request-timed-out

I've assigned a static IP address to my computer. From my computer, when I browse to [WhatIsMyIP](http://www.whatismyip.com/), I can check my IP & verify that it hasn't changed.

Now, when I ping my computer from another network, most of the times, everything is fine & I get responses; but occasionally I get 'Request Timed Out' messages (4 out of 4 attempts on:

```
CMD> ping <IP>
```

will result in the request timing out).

So far, I have not been able to identify why sometimes it works, but times out at other times. At the times it has timed out, I've used [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) to connect to my computer & check [WhatIsMyIP](http://www.whatismyip.com/) to verify that it's the same. So I know it's connected & online & everything is accessible from the computer atleast.

Normally this would not be a problem, but I'm trying to host a small website form my computer & for the most part, its online, but now & then it goes offline - even though the host computer is up & running with no change in it's IP address.

I'm on Google Fiber, if that helps. Also, under the Advanced Settings', I have reserved an IP address (192.168.1.4) for my computer so I know that will not change. And as I've mentioned my outward facing IP has been made static so I know that is always the same.

Another thing to mention, I have never faced any problems when browsing, gaming online (No disconnects or time-outs or anything)

I would like some insight as to how this can be resolved or at the very least, if the root cause can be identified.

Comment: Packet dropping is normal. TCP(which many applications use) can retransmit the lost packets, but ICMP(which ping uses) can't.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But what I'm trying to say that my computer becomes completely inaccessible at random times. I checked out a TCP version of Ping & here are the results:

    $ tcping <IP>

Probing <IP>:80/tcp - No response - time=2022.654ms
Probing <IP>:80/tcp - No response - time=2011.201ms
Probing <IP>:80/tcp - No response - time=2011.741ms
Probing <IP>:80/tcp - No response - time=2010.187ms

Ping statistics for <IP>:80
     4 probes sent.
     0 successful, 4 failed.
Was unable to connect, cannot provide trip statistics.

Comment: Can you access your computer via TeamViewer when ping times out?

Comment: @user4098326, Yep - that works fine, always. The problem is that sometimes (seemingly randomly) I'm not able to access my locally hosted website - then I checked 'ping', which shows me that it's because the request is timing out. At all these times, every other network capability seems just fine (like I can access my computer through TeamViewer & also access the internet through my computer) & all the IP addresses are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem turned out to be multiple Port Forwarding rules. I had two rules set up, one was setup to use 'Any' service & the other was setup to use only the HTTP - Port 80. I removed the 'Any' service & it's been working fine just since - I assume there was a Port Forwarding Rule conflict.